# How to create a column in SQL Server that accepts a list of inputs from ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got this html form with multi selectable checkboxes

```
            <div class="check">
    
                <label>Addons:</label>
    
                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
                <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwasht</label>


                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>


            </div>
```

Posting the input values to web API on submit through JavaScript and Created a Model in WEBAPI,

CarForm.cs :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CarServiceFormApi.Model
{
    public class CarForm
    {
        [key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<string> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }


    }
}
```

CarDbContext.cs:

```
using CarServiceFormApi.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CarServiceFormApi.Db
{
    public class CarDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CarDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CarServiceFormController.cs :

```
namespace CarServiceFormApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CarServiceFormController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CarDbContext _db;
        private static List<CarForm> CarDataList = new List<CarForm>();


        public CarServiceFormController(CarDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpPost("submit-form")]
        public IActionResult SubmitForm([FromForm] CarForm formsData)

        {


            // process the form data
 
            List<Selection> selectedCheckboxes = formsData.SelectedCheckboxes;




            // add the data to the database
            var carForm = new CarForm
            {
  
                SelectedCheckboxes= selectedCheckboxes,

            };

            _db.CarForms.Add(carForm);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            CarDataList.Add(carForm);

            return Ok(carForm);
        }
        [HttpGet("get-form-data")]
        public IActionResult GetFormData()

        {
            var data = _db.CarForms.ToList();
            return Ok(data);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to "add-migration", to create a row in database , I get an error :

```
The entity type 'List<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types
```

I too got some other simple inputs in my html form and have declared them as "string" in "CarForm.cs", they work fine except my checkboxes, as I post multiple inputs, couldn't declare them as string. I also tried declaring it as a "[keyless]" attribute but it results in  creating columns for all the other inputs except "SelectedCheckboxes".

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Database save "List" using a trick called "one to many" relationship.
For example if you have: 
car1 : "10%off First service visit"  ;"10%off Waterwash" 
car2 : "10%off Waterwash"  ; "Free AC Inspection"

Below shows how database use 2 tables to save the List .
The first table "carforms" , you will find it doesn't have a column called  "SelectedCheckboxes" but only has an "Id" column. I create 2 value to represent "car1" and "car2".

[image]

The Second table "Selections" does the trick, it has a column named "CarFormId" , which is a "foreign key" connected to the table "carfroms" key "Id" , so in this table, you can get a information that car1 is related to  "10%off First service visit" &"10%off Waterwash"   ,car2 is related to "10%off Waterwash" & "Free AC Inspection"
[image]

More clearly, if you want to change the value of "CarFormId" ,it will only let you choose "1" or "2". Because you only have car1 and car2 in the "carforms" table.
[image]

This is how the "list" saved in a database using "one to many" trick.
You will find 2 tables are necessary, so you need to create a "Selection" class.

```
public class Selection
    {
        public int SelectionId { get; set; }
        public string SlectionName { get; set; }
    }
```

And in the "CarForm" class, alternate with the `List<Selection>` because string couldn't define a table.

```
public class CarForm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<Selection> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
    }
```

And add the "selections" table in the DbContext

```
namespace CarServiceFormApi.Db
{
    public class CarDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CarDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Selection> Selections { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After doing these. You will be able to update the database successfully. And build to exactly same databse what I showed.

What I am concerning is that operating with "one to many" relationshop table is not that simple. Visaul studio can generate CURD controller automatically for simple string types but not for list. You will need to learn LINQ. Such as `_context.carforms.include(x=>x.selections)`. This not gonna be easy.
So I still recommand you to use string if it is enough for you.

Comment: I cant go with string because of the fact that I'm working with multiple checkboxes . When using string I could only store the first checkbox which gets selected and not the remaining ones. I'll try doing the above steps n update if it works

Comment: can u tell me, should I change anything in my controller(actually im trying to store and retrieve the inputs from sql using POST and GET methods). Yes, Ive updated the code.

Comment: @zack Yes, you will need change a lot of things in the controller ,and the logic to operate database. I also have no confidence about writting LINQ. I recommand you to make a new question asking about LIst database CURD to get more expert people to help.

Comment: okay sure I will

Comment: @zack Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No I watched some tutorials on that but It didn't help. Still searching

Comment: @zack Remember your 1st question? You don't have to use List<string> to save database. Just save a string to database. Whenever you use the string, split it to a list.

Comment: I tried using string but by doing so, I could only return one selected checkbox or the checkbox that I select first and not the rest and That's why I opted List but now I know its not the way I'm supposed to do. In the meantime Ive gone through a lotta results and now I kinda creating a Many to many relationship b/w tables . One to store my Form data(checkbox+name,contactnumber+a dropdown), One to store those checkbox options and the last one to link those two tables together. But I no clue on How am I going to make it through

Comment: @zack You can reference this https://mycodingtips.com/2021/3/16/sample-code-to-create-read-update-and-delete-crud-records-ef-core-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I followed this and made some changes, Can u tell me did I go wrong with this [Updated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867060/post-and-get-values-from-3-tables-linked-through-many-to-many-relationship-with/75867273#75867273)

Comment: @zack I haven't done many to many before. I will try to see if i can find something.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a connection string
2. run this command in package manager console (add-migration  e.g (add migration "initial migration"))
3. then after your connection is successful run this command "Update-database"

your build might fail, and you need to add this in your connection string
TrustServerCertificate=true;Trusted_Connection=True

Comment: Already done the above steps, but still Im not able to create a row for my "checkboxes"