# Unable to POST an array of Selected Checkboxes using Fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core-webapi

html form:

```
<form name="CarServ" id="myForm">
            <div>
                <label>CarModel:</label>
                <input type="text" id="model" size="65" name="CarModel" placeholder="Enter Car Model" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Car Number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="num" name="CarNumber" placeholder="Enter Car Number" required >
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contact number:</label>
                <input type="text" size="65" id="cnum" name="ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter your contact number" required>
            </div>


            <div id="service" class="opt">
                <label>Type of service:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="TypeOfService" id="t1" value="Waterwash"required>
                <label for="t1">Waterwash</label>
                <input type="radio" name="TypeOfService" id="t2" value="Fullservice" required>
                <label for="t1">Fullservice</label>
    
    
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div class="check">
    
                <label>Addons:</label>
    
                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
                <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwash</label>


                <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>


            </div>  

    
            <div class="dropd">
                <label>Select State:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="SelectState" id="select1">
                        <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">--SELECT--</option>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Tamilnadu</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kerala</option>
                        <option value="option3">Karnataka</option>
                        <option value="option4">Maharastra</option>
                    </select>   
            </div>
            
            <div class="dropdcontent">
                <label>Select City:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name ="SelectCity" id="select2">
                        <option value="option1">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option1">Chennai</option>
                        <option value="option1">Coimbatore</option>
                        <option value="option1">Madurai</option>
                        <option value="option2">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option2">Trivandrum</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kochi</option>
                        <option value="option2">Kollam</option>
                        <option value="option3">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option3">Bangalore</option>
                        <option value="option3">Mysore</option>
                        <option value="option4">Select State</option>
                        <option value="option4">Mumbai<option>
                        <option value="option4">Pune<option>
                  </select>     
            </div>
            <br/>
                    
            <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <input type="reset" value="RESET" onclick="clearreset()" name="reset" />    
        
    
        </form>
        <script src="formtoapi.js"></script>
```

formtoapi.cs :

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",submitForm);

function submitForm(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(event.target);

  // Convert the FormData object to a JSON object
  var json = {};
  formData.forEach((value, key) => json[key] = value);

  fetch("https://localhost:7032/api/CarServiceForm/submit-form",{
    mode:"cors",
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(json)

  })
  .then(response =>{
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("HTTP error"+response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=>{
    console.log("Success:",data);
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.error("Error:",error);
  });
}
```

CarForm.cs : the model in API to which I trying to Post the form data

```
public class CarForm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public string CarNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfService { get; set; }
        public string SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
        public string SelectState { get; set; }
        public string SelectCity { get; set; }
        public IList<Selection> ?Selections { get; set; }


    }
```

I'm able to post all the other input fields in Html form to api except **SelectedCheckboxes[]**.
When I try to post , I get an error on the console regarding fetch as :

```
POST https://localhost:7032/api/CarServiceForm/submit-form 400
SelectedCheckboxes: ["The SelectedCheckboxes field is required."]
status: 400
```

Can Anyone tell me what goes wrong in the code

Comment: Did you check, if the key is really `SelectedCheckboxes` and not `SelectedCheckboxes[]`, since that is the value of the checkbox `name` properties.

Comment: @Geshode yes, It is SelectedCheckboxes[]. Should I change it to SelectedCheckboxes? Because of the fact that i need multiple selected values, I used SelectedCheckboxes[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message means the value of checkbox can't be binded to the `SelectedCheckboxes` property successfully. From your comment, I think you want to achieve multiple selected, So you can change your code like:

**Model**

```
 public string[] SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="check">
    
                <label>Addons:</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="10%off Waterwash" id="10%off Waterwash">
                <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwash</label>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>

            </div>
```

**Js code**

```
    //..........
    var json = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => json[key] = value);
   
    //add this code in your js
    let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    let index = 0;
    let array = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++)
    {
        if (checkbox[i].checked == true) {
            array.push(checkbox[i].value);
            index++
        }
    }
    json[`SelectedCheckboxes`] = array;
  
    //........
```

**Demo**

You can check when i select the first and the third checkbox, It can bind to `SelectedCheckboxes` successfully.

[image: SelectedCheckboxes]

Comment: thats a good approach! hey can u pls share your homecontroller.cs too? would help to refer

Comment: @zack, From your js, I think you send ajax to Web api, but in my demo, For testing, I just send ajax to mvc controller, It may be a little different from yours, It just a normal action without anything special;  `[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Test([FromBody]CarForm model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }`

Comment: hey will I be able to store the same model in database if I use dbcontext and then retrieve them if I go with this?

Comment: Sry, I don't get your point, Can your explain it in more details?

Comment: I actually got my form in visual studio code and i'm passing it to api which is in visual studio and need to store it in a database. I should be able to post and retrieve inputs from database back to the console.

Comment: Of course you can. If you don't know how to do it, According to the policy ,You need to post another question about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> formData.append(json[key], value)

for appending all your checkbox value in formData and then pass it in your API call if API is only accepting in FormData

Comment: Just tried and got an error 'formtoapi.js:292 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).